# Is it possible to code Wordpress theme without php?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just signed up to Wordpress today and am already having several issues. I'm a front end developer, so I don't know a lot of php (I know some very basics). I tired to figure out how to add my own themes to Wordpress (basically I heard that you just code website normally with html, css and javascript like you usually would and then upload files to Wordpress). However I can't find this option anywhere, only changes I'm able to make are in GUI editor of current themes available in Wordpress. Can anyone explain how it works?

Comment: It is just html/css but it's broken up into templates. There will be blocks of PHP to tell the theme "show X posts here" and stuff, which you can copy/paste and edit the HTML around.

Comment: You can use "Wordpress template frameworks" to create child themes using only CSS. You can also create a child theme of any other template that you like, using only CSS. Like sachleen says, if you do decide to edit the template you will need to edit PHP files but the functions you will encounter will just be stuff like "put post content here". Most people don't learn these functions by heart, they edit existing templates and the functions are named so one understands what they do.

Comment: You can create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) with just a style sheet.

Comment: You only need the very basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general answer is no. Wordpress is built with PHP and content is served to the user using PHP.

Now, if you are just starting out and don't want to learn PHP here's my suggestion.

Find a theme as close to what you want your site to look like.
Then you can just modify the HTML, CSS and JS that supports the theme.
If you're not making drastic changes it should be fairly simple.

Comment: won't that be any illegal to copy somebody else's code?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you copy it. I'm suggesting you legally acquire the existing theme, and then tweak it to match your needs. This is how a lot of web design agencies work.